# How to disable error messages in PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

How do I disable the error messages from the PHPMailer class? I'm displaying my own error messages and I don't want users to see errors such as "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."

Thanks

Comment: phpmailer has a `verbose` property. I don't have a copy handy so I can't check out the exact name but it was something to that effect - check out the top of the class file, it should be there

Comment: I found $ErrorInfo but it doesn't matter if i comment out the line. Still showing error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not probably the best solution, but it works.

In your phpmailer library folder open "class.phpmailer.php",

find

```
public function Send()
```

inside it comment the line

```
echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
```

Comment: $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; will stop all warning/notice

Answer (score 29):

I know this thread is old and already answered but I stumbled here because I had the same problem but ending up solving it differently so I thought I'd share. NOTE: I'm using PHPMailer v5.1.

When you instantiate the PHPMailer class, it takes one optional argument, $exceptions.  That tells PHPMailer if it should throw exceptions if it encounters any.  It defaults to false which means it does not throw any exceptions, just echoes its messages out.  However, if you call it like

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

you will tell it to throw exceptions. You can then catch those exceptions and deal with them however you choose.  To me, that is much cleaner and more elegant than messing with the source code or disabling the error reporting.

Answer (score 18):

This is the way PHPMailer wants you to do it; does not involve editing the original class file.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->do_debug = 0;
```

Comment: For test purposes I turned off my mail server, and even though I put in these lines  $mail = new PHPMailer(false);
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
  $mail->do_debug = 0; I still get a line coming up in the console saying Could not instantiate mail function. Very annoying as it is stopping my json code return to jQuery

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that work pretty much the same as of May 2020

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

OR 

$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a better solution (I think :) ), it's an improved version of the solution sugested by Riccardo

In the file "class.phpmailer.php", within the function

```
public function Send()
```

find the line

```
echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
```

and replace it for this

```
if ($SMTPDebug)
   echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
```

In this way, it will only show the exceptions messages (or error messages) if you are running in debug mode..

Hope it helps!!
regards!!

Comment: You should avoid editing the class.phpmailer.php file. Makes for difficult upgrades in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

```
ob_start(); //start output buffering to capture all output and prevent errors from being displayed
$delivery = $mail->Send();
ob_end_clean(); //erase the buffer and stop output buffering
```

I needed to suppress errors from the JUtility::sendMail function in Joomla, which uses PHPMailer behind the scenes, so the above answers didn't work for me but output buffering did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the errors are coming from the call to `$mail->Send();` then you can do something like this:

```
$oldErrorSetting = error_reporting(0); // temporarily disable warnings
$delivery = $mail->Send();
error_reporting($oldErrorSetting); // restore error setting
```

This will suppress PHP errors that come from the Send call.

Then, to get PHPMailer's errors and do something nice with them, you can use the `$delivery` return value and `ErrorInfo`:

```
if (!$delivery) {
    $errorDetails = $mail->ErrorInfo;
    print "<p>$errorDetails</p>\n";
}
```

Comment: I can't get it to work, i must be doing something wrong, I tried implementing your code but no luck. Please see http://pastie.org/1497819 for my original code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a problem with the error: Can not modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php) because my return json needs header ('Content-Type: application / json') ; And was giving error because the class class.phpmailer.php printed on the screen the error Invalid address: which generates the error of the header so to solve it was simple, it only includes in the class class.phpmailer.php in the following line the debug check and it worked Perfectly follows

This line

```
Echo $ this-> Lang ('invalid_address'). ':'. $ Address;
```

Change to:

```
If ($ this-> SMTPDebug) {
       Echo $ this-> Lang ('invalid_address'). ':'. $ Address;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete below code if included

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
```