# Ajax and PHPMailer error

Tags: javascript, ajax, phpmailer

I'm improving a code, but i'm getting some troubles.

I'm trying to send an email to one of my users. If the email exist i got no problem, instead if doesn't exist the website app explode.

This is my js code using ajax:

```
callAjax(url, paramsInsert, true, function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        modal("OK", "<h3>ALL OK</h3>", "OK");
    } else {
        modal("error", "<h3> ERROR </h3>", "Error");
    }
});
```

And this is my Ajax function:

```
function callAjax(url, parametros, load, funcion) {

if (load) {
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.id = "loadBackground";
    element.className = "backLoad";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = '<div class="loadImage"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><img class="center-block" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /></div><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div></div></div>';
}

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
        //var datos = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

        var jsontext = ajax.responseText;

        var content = eval('(' + jsontext + ')');
        //if (content.success) {
        funcion(content);
        if (load) {
            document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = '';
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("loadBackground"));
        }
        // }

    }
};
ajax.open("POST", url, true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax.send(parametros);
```

}

If mail is incorrect i'm getting this error on console of the broswer:

> jsontext = "SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: gjdfhgdf@dfgndfjkgd.com: : Recipient address rejected: Domain not found
>   ↵{"success":false}"

The problem is that i don't get inside the else "callAjax" function.

How can i get inside that else when i get an error on wrong mail?

**EDIT:**

My php code is something like this:

```
$enviarEmail = $this->sendMAIL($_SESSION['idenUser'], $totalconDescuento, $envioDesc, $_POST['sin_assistente']);

    if (!$enviarEmail) {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'jsontext' => 'Error']);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'jsontext' => 'OK']);
    }
```

Still getting same error:

> jsontext = "SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: gjdfhgdf@dfgndfjkgd.com: : Recipient address rejected: Domain not found
>   ↵{"success":false,"jsontext":"Error"}"

I also tried to add parameters when i create new PHPMailer:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(false);

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = false;
    $mail->do_debug = 0;
```

Found on this post: [Disable PHPMailer error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798498/disable-phpmailer-error-messages)

**Solution:**

I found through functions this code:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $estado = false;
    }
```

So i just commented fisrt lane to disable Errorinfo print :)

Comment: Should be fixable by simply setting PHPMailer to not show any debug output, no?

Comment: @CBroe I tried, lokk at edit :(

Comment: What you say you are getting as output, does not match the PHP code you have shown. It makes no sense whatsoever that the `jsontext` property would contain anything other than either `Error` or `OK`, because those are the only two values you ever set for that property in the code you have shown.

Comment: Yup, looks like you've not included all your code here. At the receiving end, `jsontext` will contain everything that was output by your script, so you must have some other output as well as the intended JSON content.

Comment: @Synchro you were right i edit the post because i found that piece of code through functions. Thanks!

Comment: @CBroe Post edited i found it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get into that `else` you need to make sure that `data.success` contains a value that will not be considered `true`, and that's up to what you return from PHP, not what's in your JS.

If you want to process the return value as JSON, you need to actually return JSON from your PHP - which your example `jsontext` is not.

In your PHP it would be something like:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'jsontext' => $mail->ErrorInfo]);
} else {
    echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'jsontext' => 'OK']);
}
```